# Junit4 - Cleanup on test timeout

Tags: java, timeout, junit4

When I run a test with annotation @Test(timeout = 3000) and it times out, it kills the test immediately and does not call my tearDown method annotated with @After.

What would be the way to clean up in such a scenario?

EDIT: 
My test is invoking resource end points using jax-rs over the wire and the test times out in the middle of a http request. This is the case I am fairly certain that @After is not being invoked

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, it doesn't kill the test, it fails it. Which apparently means that the method annotated with `@After` will run.

The code below is working like charm for me.

```
@Test(timeout=1)
public void testTimeout() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
}

@After
public void after() {
    System.out.println("@After is invoked, indeed.");
}
```

Output is,

```
Testsuite: javaapplication1.MainTest
After is invoked, indeed.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.054 sec
```

Comment: Yes, I am using @After and on timeout that does not seem to be called.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with the timeout attribute, too. Maybe this helps you in finding four problem...

In my case the confusion was caused by the fact that the test code in a method annotated with @Test(timeout=...) is run in a separate thread. Therefore some ThreadLocal stuff I accessed during the test could not be cleaned up in the @After method.

Comment: My bad, i should have given more info. My test invokes a bunch of resource end points using jax-rs over the wire, so I am really not sure what happens when a test times out in the middle of http request, I think it just kills all the threads spawned by the test. Are you talking something similar?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Rule  
public Timeout to = new Timeout(300000);
```

This works from JUnit 4.7.